# Import Elasticsearch 2.X data to 6.X?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I've got some data/logs from Elasticsearch 2.4 & I've got a new Elasticsearch 6.X running.

What's the best/correct way to import data from 2.X to 6.x?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you followed the documentation?

Comment: Documentation on upgrade path says to upgrade to 5.X, reindex, then to 6.X & reindex again (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-upgrading-v6.html#ec-upgrading-v6-reindex). I was wondering if there's a more simple way to do that?

Comment: By default, following the instructions in the documentation *is* the best way to do such an upgrade.

Comment: @Sven c'mon, this is a legitimate question. There is often undocumented ways of doing things, and sometimes documentation is poor and doesn't offer solutions. There was nothing wrong with this question except for your demand that anything that's RTFM is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get in-situ data from a 2.x index into a 6.x index without doing a progressive upgrade and dealing with the breaking changes that occur during each upgrade.

Additionally you may find that it is impossible to migrate from 2.x to 6.x without changing your document structure, as certain things that were legal in 2.x were deprecated in 5.x and removed in 6.x

Given that ElasticSearch is not meant to be the primary source of any data, the typical way of going going between unsupported versions is to start with a blank cluster and then re-index all of your data.

Of course I realise this is not always possible, or sometimes infeasable due to the volume of data. But there's no other way.

Re-index everything, or go through the upgrade path between versions.